# How to clone git repositories on redmine?

Tags: git, redmine

I configure my repo as */home/repo/gitrepo/myproj.git* on redmine.

Now, i want to clone it on my laptop but i cannot see the *url*

what url should i use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this for personal use, you could be well done with accessing your repository via ssh.

```
git clone repo@machine.address.com:gitrepo/myproj.git
```

However, you might want to search for a more powerful Redmine plugin for Git support, or use repository management system, such as [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way).

Comment: It's not for personal use.  I tried **git clone repo@machine.address.com:gitrepo/myproj.git** but it keeps on asking the password even if I entered the right password.  What do you think is the problem? Thanks in advance..

Comment: @vinyuri, then the password either isn't set up, or login for that user (repo) is forbidden with password, and this might be an issue of SSH server configuration.  We use gitosis in pair with Redmine, which I advise to you too.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use some git repositories manager to do this, and I recommend to use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) for small case, see guideline http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html, then you can do as follow

1. mostly use git user to do git clone, so migrate /home/repo/gitrepo/myproj.git to /home/git/repositories/myproj.git
2. re-config it in redmine using new git directory

In more professional way (I think) is to set git repo seperately and sync to redmine git repo.

1. you can setup git repo by gitolite or gerrit in other place
2. run git sync (crontab like) to sync this git repo into your local git repo.

The second case is more independant and easy to manage by different people.

Answer (score -1):

How to clone a git repository in windows ?

- Install git bash to the computer
- Open git bash command prompt
- Go to the correct folder location :

  - cd /F -> (for change to the F partition)
  - Using cd got to the location path :- Sunburst
  - Create folder :- mkdir Source
  - Type :- git clonehttps://integritas.git.beanstalkapp.com/sunburst.git(git repoitory URL) and click enter button
- You can see the repository is downloading. Sometimes it will ask the username and the password which access of repository URL is contained site